Enum class name is used instead of value
Newbie here trying to use json serialization using mappers for a class that contains a enum. I find the classname is used in the request sent instead of the enum value.N ot sure what I missed here. The target classes are auto generated from yaml through open-api
The field has @JsonValue and also I tried
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING)
Any pointers would be greatly helpful.
Thanks
Code snippets:
Mapper calling code :
CDRequest CDRequest = new CDRequest();
CDIdentifier CDIdentifier = new CDIdentifier();
CDIdentifier.setInputType(InputTypeEnum.LEGACY);
CDRequest.setInputIdentifier(CDIdentifier);
String c = mapper.writeValueAsString(CDRequest);

Target Generated code:
public class CDRequest {
    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_INPUT_IDENTIFIER = "inputIdentifier";
    private CDIdentifier inputIdentifier;
    public CDRequest inputIdentifier(CDIdentifier inputIdentifier) {
        this.inputIdentifier = inputIdentifier;
        return this;
    }

    @jakarta.annotation.Nullable
    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_INPUT_IDENTIFIER)
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    public CDIdentifier getInputIdentifier() {
        return inputIdentifier;
    }


    @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_INPUT_IDENTIFIER)
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
    public void setInputIdentifier(CDIdentifier inputIdentifier) {
        this.inputIdentifier = inputIdentifier;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = "inputType", // ignore manually set inputType, it will 
        be automatically generated by Jackson during serialization
        allowSetters = true // allows the inputType to be set during 
        deserialization
    )
    
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
        JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "inputType", visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CR.class, name = "CUSTOMER_ID"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CN.class, name = "CUSTOMER_NUMBER"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LCR.class, name = "LEGACY"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CR.class, name = "CR"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CN.class, name = "CN"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LCR.class, name = "LCR"),
    })
}

Identifier :
public class CDIdentifier {
    /**
     * Gets or Sets inputType
     */
    public enum InputTypeEnum {
        LEGACY("LEGACY");

        private String value;

        InputTypeEnum(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static InputTypeEnum fromValue(String value) {
            for (InputTypeEnum b : InputTypeEnum.values()) {
                if (b.value.equals(value)) {
                    return b;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
        }
  }

  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_INPUT_TYPE = "inputType";
  protected InputTypeEnum inputType;

Instead of the value "Legacy" the mapper returns the class name "CDIdentifier" itself, the enum value is returned from mapper.writeAsStirng.

Hi all.. I have been trying with mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING) . But did not help. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

There is something funky going on here since Jackson should never return "CDIdentifier". Can you post the JSON that´s getting generated?

Problem with JsonTypeInfo annotation. Please add to the question the source data for the CDIdentifier class

Use @JsonFormat annotation:
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
protected InputTypeEnum inputType;

Modify your OpenAPI specification to specify enum values directly in the OpenAPI YAML or JSON file by setting type to string. To ensure the generated enum values will be treated as strings helping Jackson serialize them correctly:
components:
  schemas:
    CDIdentifier:
      type: object
      properties:
        inputType:
          type: string
          enum:
            - LEGACY
            - CUSTOMER_ID
            - CUSTOMER_NUMBER
            - LCR
          description: Enum for InputType with specific values

Also some OpenAPI generators support optional x-jackson-annotations vendor extension, which allows you to add annotations like @JsonFormat directly to the specification to control how Jackson serializes and deserializes the enum values:
components:
  schemas:
    CDIdentifier:
      type: object
      properties:
        inputType:
          type: string
          enum:
            - LEGACY
          x-jackson-annotations:
            - "@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)"

If your vendor extensions supported it and provide this additional control over serialization it should help you add this annotation without modifying the generated code directly.

Thank you Kapandron. Since my target classes are auto generated using open-api not sure how to add this.

Try to edit your OpenAPI specification to influence how classes are generated, including control of enum serialization behavior.
